# ~~ Operator In Postgres

Tags: postgresql, operators

I have a query in [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.profn FROM tprof a, sap_tstc b, tgrc c 
WHERE ((c.grcid ~~ a.grcid) 
AND ((c.tcode) = (b.tcode)));
```

What is `~~` mean?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [9.7.1. LIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) of PostgreSQL documentation:

> The operator `~~` is equivalent to `LIKE`, and `~~*` corresponds to `ILIKE`. There are also `!~~` and `!~~*` operators that represent `NOT LIKE` and `NOT ILIKE`, respectively. **All of these operators are PostgreSQL-specific.**

Answer (score 6):

It isn't listed in the [index of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bookindex.html) which is frustrating.

So I had a look with `psql`:

```
regress=> \do ~~
                                     List of operators
   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |       Description       
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------
 pg_catalog | ~~   | bytea         | bytea          | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
 pg_catalog | ~~   | character     | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
 pg_catalog | ~~   | name          | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
 pg_catalog | ~~   | text          | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
(4 rows)
```

It's an operator alias for `LIKE`, that's all.